# ganglia and host sFlow custom metrics

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, metrics, ganglia

25.6 and Ganglia 3.6.

I want to extract some metrics from a program and send them with host sFlow. I've enabled the json ports in the hsflow configuration file but I don't know how to send the metrics to the host sFLow and also how to collect them with Ganglia

What is the best way for doing this?. Maybe there are other solutions instead of using the json ports but I don't know which is the best one

The host sflow is running in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use gmetric to supplement Host sFlow's standard metrics with your own custom metrics:

http://sourceforge.net/p/host-sflow/mailman/message/29438950/

Comment: Thank you, it worked well. I saw this link before but the thing is that I'm not using the sflow standard and I would like to use it. I think that using gmetric.py the metrics are sent using the Ganglia packet format instead sflow stardard.

Am I right ?